# How to use default and a custom sort together in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently using the on-click sort functionality on my table & is working fine. But now I also need to sort my table in descending order of `dateCol` on page load. So that, initially the table would be sorted in descending order of `dateCol` column & if we click on column header, the appropriate sort should also work.

Here's my code -

```
$scope.sort = function(keyname){

    if($scope.ref.displayTxnList && $scope.ref.displayTxnList.length > 0)
        if(checkDuplicateInObject(keyname,$scope.ref.displayTxnList) > 1)
        {
            if ($scope.sortKey == keyname) {
                $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
            } else {
                $scope.sortKey = keyname;  
                $scope.reverse = false;
            }   
        }
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
}
```

And the snippet is -

```
<table class="table table-hover table-standard">
    <thead>
        <th ng-click="sort('dateCol')"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="t in ref.displayTxnList | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | startFrom:( currentPage - 1 ) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to the **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)**, we can provide multiple arguments to `orderBy` as - `| orderBy : expression : reverse : comparator`. So, making use of the same, we can use one more `orderBy` as follows -

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in ref.displayTxnList | orderBy:'dateCol':false | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | startFrom:( currentPage - 1 ) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize track by $index">
    ...
</tr>
```

**Where,** I've provided *`reverse`* as *`false`*, which gives me a descending order.